# Ext/JS 4.1 - Grid Header Scrolling

Tags: extjs, header, grid, panel, extjs4.1

I am dynamically re configuring an Ext.grid.Panel.  I am passing in a store and the column configuration via the reconfigure method.  I need to be able to have the column headers stay fixed when scrolling vertically.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Here is the code I am using to dynamically create the grid:

```
var me = this,
    srStore = me.getStore('SearchResults'),
    cols = srStore.data.getAt(0).get('columnHeader'),
    columnConfig = [],
    fields =  [];

for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    columnConfig.push({ text: cols[i].replace(/_/g, ' '), dataIndex: cols[i] });
    fields.push(cols[i]);
}

var resultsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: fields,
    data: srStore.data.getAt(0).get('results')
});

me.getSearchResultsGrid().reconfigure(resultsStore, columnConfig);
```

Thanks for your help.

Jamie

Comment: What do you mean by " I need to be able to have the column headers **stay fixed** when scrolling vertically"

Comment: Please post a screenshot to help us understand.

Comment: This is already the default behavior of grids. What happens when you reconfigure?